# Change tint color of UITextFields clear Button

Tags: uitextfield, ios11

i tried to change the color of uitextfields clear button like:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.urlTextField.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subView;
        [button setImage:[[button imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

I'm able to add a custom image this way, but the tint color won't change.

Answer (score 0):

As i could´nt find a solution to change the tint color of the original picture, i´ve implemented this workaround

```
-(void)setClearButtonColor: (UIColor *) color forTextfield: (UITextField *) textField{

    UIButton *clearButton = [textField valueForKey:@"_clearButton"];

    if (clearButton) {

        UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldClearButton"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        [clearButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [clearButton setTintColor: color];
    }
}
```

i have created this clear button image (57x57)(@3x)

[image]

feel free to use it.